# Sorting Gridview on a calculated field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

I have a gridview that displays a calculated field, based on a db source field it populates with.

can i sort by it? i can't seem to figure out how to do it?

example:

my templatefield looks like this:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="category" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# BuildCategory(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.category")) %>'
             ID="lblPrice"></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

where category is party of the datasource, but what gets displayed is a calculated value - which is different from the category.

what can i put in the "SOrtExpression" to make it sort by the new value - taht gets displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you probably want to do this before you assign the datasource. Process the datasource (with your calculated field), and *then* feed it to your grid.

So your process might look something like:

1. Retrieve dataset
2. Add/Process Calculated field
3. Sort the dataset and bind it to the
   grid **OR** first bind the dataset to
   the grid and then you can use the
   grid's functions to sort it if
   supported.